# How to import publicly available jelastic manifests from gitlab repositories in the jelastic dashboard?

Tags: gitlab, jelastic

I am currently transitioning from github to gitlab. Today, my code is present at both those locations. I have a jps manifest on github:

https://github.com/shopozor/services/blob/master/manifest.jps

and the very same manifest on gitlab:

https://gitlab.hidora.com/softozor/services/blob/master/manifest.jps

In the Jelastic dashboard, I am able to load my github manifest. However, I am not able to load my manifest versioned on gitlab:

[image]

What is the problem? Do I have to configure something special somewhere? Both manifests are publicly available. Why can't I import the gitlab manifest?

I also tried to use the raw manifest:

https://gitlab.hidora.com/softozor/services/raw/master/manifest.jps

and I've also tried to get the manifest file by means of the [gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository), without success.

### EDIT

I've tried to load [this manifest](https://gitlab.hidora.com/softozor/services/blob/install-postgres-in-dedicated-env/jelastic/postgres/manifest.jps). There we see that I am running a command

```
wget "${baseUrl}/jelastic/postgres/execCmdScript.sh" -O /var/lib/pgsql/script.sh 2>&1
```

In the jelastic console, that command raises the error

```
[07:56:54 Shopozor.cluster:2]: ERROR: cmd [sqldb: 62900].response: {" result": 4109," source": “JEL”," error": “The operation could not be performed. ”," errOut": ""," nodeid": 62900," exitStatus": 4," out": “--2020-03-27 07:56:53-- https://gitlab.hidora.com/softozor/services/raw/install-postgres-in-dedicated-env/jelastic/postgres/execCmdScript.sh\nResolving gitlab.hidora.com (gitlab.hidora.com)... 10.102.1.82\nConnecting to gitlab.hidora.com (gitlab.hidora.com)|10.102.1.82|:443... failed: Connection refused.”}
```

If I now take a computer which I never authenticated with on gitlab through ssh, and run that very same command, then it works. This is a bit strange, isn't it? What authentication does Jelastic need??? it's all public and available to anyone, except Jelastic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I was finally able to load my manifests from gitlab into jelastic. The problem is probably due to the gitlab configuration. Loading the jps from the gitlab repo doesn't work over https in the settings I have (which I haven't made myself, it's a CI / CD as a service). It works, however, over http.